# Notifying multiple listeners

Tags: design-patterns

I am building an Android guitar application and I need a way for `GuitarString` objects to notify multiple listeners that it has just been played. This includes the current `Activity` and all instances of `GuitarStringView` that have it as their `GuitarString` (the guitar is displayed twice, zoomed in & out).

I have so far handled this by having a `ArrayList<OnPlayedListener>` on `GuitarString` and each `GuitarStringView` or `Activity` adds themselves to that list. My `Guitar` class is a Singleton (which I know some may frown upon) so now I have to make sure objects remove themselves from the array of listeners when they're disposed of.

So my question is, is this a good approach, or is there a pattern that I should be using to handle this?

Comment: Observer pattern is very good for this.

Comment: Thank you, yes it looks ideal. If you make that your answer then I'll accept it

Comment: In good faith I can't make it an answer because I'm still learning about design patterns and was actually on the chapter that discussed the observer pattern, and the explanation was kinda exactly what you asked for.

Comment: @PieterB - Nonsense.  You can certainly make it an answer--just because it is newly learned does not mean it is not appropriate to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the Observer Pattern, AKA publisher/subscribe (pubsub). It's exactly what you need here.
Here is a great video of Derek Banas explaining how it works :

[Observer Pattern Derek Banas](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiQdrH2YpT4&list=PLF206E906175C7E07&index=4)

Comment: This would be a grade A+ answer with a little explanation/summary of what is described in the video.